# JavaFX: Missing return statement

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I have the following code that does the following:
- It takes a temperature and a channel index and searches through a list of objects (that contain temperature arrays) and returns the index of the object where the temperature is found.
I want this method to end when it finds the first one since this is the earliest time at which the temperature was reached (it's logged)

```
public int findRow(double targetTemperature, int ch)
{
    //This method takes a double and finds it in the List, it then returns the element in which it is (the row)
    //The element returned can be used with duration.between to find the response time between 2 known values
    for (int i=0; i < readings.size(); i++)
    {
            double compareTemp = readings.get(i).getValue(ch);
            if (compareTemp > targetTemperature)
            {
                System.out.println(readings.get(i).getTimestamp() + "is above target temp for channel " + ch);
                return i;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(readings.get(i).getTimestamp() + "Is not above target temp for channel " + ch);
                return 0;
            }
    }
}
```

The List contains TemperatureReadings which is a class I created that has two variables:
- values array of doubles
- timestamp with currentime (when the array was created)
I'm trying to find the response time for each channel. However, when I run the above code it says that "there is no return statement" even though both options have a return statement (if/else)
Or if you can help me make a better method to find the FIRST OCCURENCE of the list where the temperature in that channel (array index) reached X degrees I would really appreciate it.

Actually I would not like it to return 0 if possible to return an error or something saying "no temperature was found" or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuyen is correct. Also, you don't want the else statement. You'll return after the first item. You'll just want the first if, then outside the loop return 0;

Try:

```
public int findRow(double targetTemperature, int ch)
{
    //This method takes a double and finds it in the List, it then returns the element in which it is (the row)
    //The element returned can be used with duration.between to find the response time between 2 known values
    for (int i=0; i < readings.size(); i++)
    {
            double compareTemp = readings.get(i).getValue(ch);
            if (compareTemp > targetTemperature)
            {
                System.out.println(readings.get(i).getTimestamp() + "is above target temp for channel " + ch);
                return i;
            }
    }
    System.out.println(readings.get(i).getTimestamp() + "Is not 
            above target temp for channel " + ch);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Incorrect: it returns 0 both in case of no element has been found, and in case of the first element fits the criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Because your if statement is inside your loop, what happen if your loop do not run? ==> mean that you have no return statement!
Add a return statement out of your loop, although you know that it can not run this statement just because you sure the loop will run, but the compiler is not know that

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is incorrect: If the first element does not fit the condition, the method will return in the else branch without even checking the other elements of the list.

You could remove the else brach, and make a convention (and javadoc comment, that -1 is returned if no item has been found with the specified criteria) ...

```
public int findRow(double targetTemperature, int ch) {
    for (int i = 0; i < readings.size(); i++) {
        if (readings.get(i).getValue(ch) > targetTemperature)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

... and you can log anything based on the return value on the caller side:

```
int channel = 2;
int ind = findRow(35, channel);
if (ind >= 0)
    System.out.println(readings.get(ind).getTimestamp() + " is above target temp for channel " + channel);
else
    System.out.println("Nothing has been found");
```

---

The same using a stream:

```
public int findRow(double targetTemperature, int ch) {
    return IntStream.range(0, readings.size())
            .filter(i -> readings.get(i).getValue(ch) > targetTemperature)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(-1);
}
```